# What modifications should I buy for my Vigilance Guardian?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

### Introduction

I recently hit Level 65 with my Vigilance Guardian and I'm about half-way through Shadows of Revan. Before I start Knights of the Fallen Empire, I intend to do a big (and potentially expensive) overhaul of my gear, or rather the modifications within my gear.

I am looking to acquire a full set of modifications (armorings, mods, enhancements, hilts, augmentations) aimed at Tanking.

### Question

**What modifications and augments should I get to optimise my Vigilance Guardian for tanking?**

#### Notes

- I know the Vigilance Discipline is not optimal for tanking, but as I am the only one that would consider being the "cannon fodder", I would like to be able to gear myslef towards that end.
- I do not intend to be the main tank in any Operation, Flashpoint, Warzone or other Group Finder activity. I simply want to be able to soak up alot of the damage when doing H2+ missions or Planetary Storylines with my two glass cannon friends.
- I would love to receive a full "shopping" list in your answer(s) and, if possible, advice on how to get the different items
- I know that I should no BUY each individual modification, but rather get them with/from equipment and possibly crafting, but I would still like to know which modifications are preferred.
- I will be slotting modifications into Cartel Market equipment as I have no interest or intention of using Outfit Designer, which may mean that I have to extract mods from equipment in order to get the best mods (and I'm fine with that)

Comment: Please ask your questions separately next time.

Comment: Please explain the down vote so that I can update the question to eliminate the problem.

Comment: Post is now updated to hold only 1 question.

Comment: +1 vote because its not a bad question, but it is a bad idea. this game does not allow such creativity in its classes and relies to much on a bottlenecked system for its dps/heal/tank roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot tank in DPS spec, the concept is absurd.  Without tanking abilities and buffs, tanking gear would be mostly useless and gimp your DPS,  ensuring you could not maintain threat.  DPS gear won't offer you any protection and it is likely that you would still not maintain threat over other DPS who are more familiar with the role and their Disciplines.

Since you are 65, you should also not buy individual mods. The Data Crystal vendors on Fleet sell complete gear sets for each role -- you would get the Pummeler set for DPS, or the Bulwark set for tanking (in tank spec).  Better-optimized versions of these sets drop from Operations.

Current stat priorities for DPS are 110% Accuracy, plus Crit and Alacrity in about a 3:2 ratio (see [this forum post](http://www.swtor.com/community/showpost.php?p=8558149&postcount=2)). For tanks, it's approximately 2:1:1 for Defense, Shield, and Absorb ([source](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=842859)).  How you achieve those ratios is up you, since many combinations of mods can work.

If you absolutely MUST attempt to "tank" as a DPS, the only thing that's really going to help you is Defense.  That means Redoubt augments, Warding mods, and a mix of Sturdiness and Immunity enhancements.

Comment: I once ran a HM flashpoint where the guy who'd signed up for the tank role turned out - as we discovered after wiping on the first throwaway boss -  to be a DPS-specced Guardian in full PVP gear. He couldn't hold aggro and couldn't survive the incoming damage in the few cases where he did have it.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear in my question. I am not intending to act as a full-blown Tank in Operations and/or Flashpoints via Group Finder or otherwise. I want to have gear that would allow me to take a lot of hits in, for example, H2 mission and Planetary Stories while grouping with my two Glass cannon friends (Gunslinger and Shadow). I'll update my question.

Comment: Further, I understand that I shouldn't buy individual modifications, but I would still like to know which mods I should be focusing on. I'll update my question to clarify this.

Comment: @GunnarSödergren I've added a little bit to my answer, but I still maintain that this is not a good idea.  By using non-DPS mods all you will really do is slow down how fast you kill things, meaning that you will take more damage over the long run.  For a DPS, the best defence is a good offence; no matter what, you're not going to be able to take a lot of hits.  Guardian is excellent in terms of cooldowns, particularly Focused Defense, but they will run out quickly and leave you with none of the tank-specific buffs.

Comment: @GunnarSödergren Tank specs usually have a wide area of AoE attacks to hold agro better. If you want to take this tour anyway i would suggest that you go as tank spec with a shield generator and use less tank mods/enhancements and more dps orientated gear. That would be more optimal, otherwise i also do not see the point why u would need defense if you have 2 other people with you to run such basic content, set a companion to tank mode and that will be more efficient then what you are asking for. And as someone already said, If you try group content, you'll be kicked nearly instantly

Comment: Ah, there's an idea. Tank Spec with DPS-y gear. And keep a second set of  (actual Tank) gear for when playing group content as a Tank.

Comment: @MatthewRead I'll revisemy question to reflect the point made by Vahx. I'd love it if you'd update your answer, as I'm sure you have great insight and can provide me with great tips.

Comment: @GunnarSödergren If you want to ask a different question, please post it separately rather than completely overhauling the existing question.  That said, my answer fully applies to DPSing while in tank spec -- 110% Accuracy and the 3:2 Crit:Alacrity ratio, and that it's not a great idea.

Comment: Alright, my bad. Thanks for editing the question back. :)